# Cannot Change Update Channel in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, macos-sierra, visual-studio-mac

I had installed Visual Studio for Mac Preview in a few week ago. As a default update channel, my update channel is in "Stable" instead of "Beta" or "Alpha". I can change the update channel easily.
But now the option for "Stable" and "Beta" has gone. I don't know what's going on there. My update channel is now only showing "Alpha". My Visual Studio for Mac performance is worse than before.
[image]

How to bring back the "Stable" channel option? I want to go back to Stable channel but still no idea how to do that.
This is my last version of my Visual Studio for Mac

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible anymore.

See: https://releases.xamarin.com/preview-7-visual-studio-for-mac/

> Please note that the VS for Mac IDE has its own set of updater channels, separate from Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.VS. As of Preview 6 and for all future Preview releases of VS for Mac, only an Alpha channel will appear. That channel provides the latest preview updates as they become available. When VS for Mac moves out of preview status, the available updater channels will be adjusted accordingly. It should be noted that since VS for Mac is still in preview, it is not yet a fully supported product.

Comment: As of May 10 2017 Visual Studio for Mac became generally available and now is possible to select the stable channel